# How to delete activity log being guest user . so that root user cant track activity

Tags: command-line, permissions, guest-session

i use an Ubuntu laptop as guest user , i think the root user is spying on me. so how can i delete activity log being guest for my session or how to enable Ubuntu to not show my acttivity log in terminal of root user.
thanks in advance.

Comment: No way, you would need root-privileges to do so.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the system? If so, you can do whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You would need root permissions for that, and if you're in as the guest user, you have no privileges.  There's no way around that.

Also consider that the 'root user' is god on the computer - they will have access to everything on the system, so it's not just a case of "deleting the activity logs".  It's more than likely that if they actually are lurking your activity they're doing it at the networking level or offloading the log reporting component elsewhere (like malware would do) to a third-party location that you wouldn't be able to work with.

Ultimately, if you feel that you are being spied on by the 'root' user or the system administrators and are using an unprivileged "guest" account, you should not be using that computer and should probably consider using your own trusted system instead.